# How to change XML attributes (and values) with SimpleXMLElement in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I got a problem when I set a value/attribute of XML tag.
This is my PHP code:

```
$f=simplexml_load_file("String.xml");
$f2=$f->imgdir;
foreach($f2 as $imgdir)
{
    $st=$imgdir->string;

    foreach($st as $str)
    {
        $fd=$str->attributes();
        $fd['value']='New Value';
    }
}
$f->asXML("String.xml");
```

And this is my String.xml file's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<imgdir name="Cash.img">
    <imgdir name="5000011">
        <string name="name" value="Monkey"/>
        <string name="desc" value="A lovely effect that shows a baby angel floating around as your protector.  Designate a HotKey to turn the effect on/off."/>
    </imgdir>
    <imgdir name="5010000">
        <string name="name" value="Sunny Day"/>
        <string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see a brightly smiling sun floating over you. On the KeyConfig, configure this on a button of your choice to turn the effect on/off."/>
    </imgdir>
</imgdir>
```

How can I change the value attribute of per `<string>` tag and save the XML file? What should I do with my current code?

Thank for reading my question!

Comment: your code is changing value="New value" for <string> . what you want ?

Comment: @Vegeta: I want to know that with the operation (value="New value"), can I change to the XML file?

Comment: ya.. $f->asXML("String.xml"); statement saves content into file itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Basics**

I suggest you select all `<string>` nodes with `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$strings = $xml->xpath("//string");
```

The above statement will select all `<string>` nodes as `SimpleXml` elements into an array.
The double slash in `//string` will take `<string>` regardless of their position in the tree.

Now it is simple to iterate over `$strings` and set the new value:

```
foreach ($strings as $string) 
    $string["value"] = "new value";
```

Note that the changes applied to `$strings` happen in `$xml`, so:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

will show the changes.

see it working: https://eval.in/499427

**Expanded**

Of course, you might want to select only certain `<string>` nodes, e.g. all having `name="name"`. In this case, you can tell `xpath` like:

```
$strings = $xml->xpath("//string[@name='name']");
```

Note the condition set in `[]` and `@name` referring to the `attribute` name.